Inconsistency of character indexes while trying to parse multiple JSON in a file
I am using the following code to parse JSON multiline objects separated by comma from a webscraped string stored in a .json file:
import json

def stream_read_json(fn):
    start_pos = 0
    with open(fn, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                obj = json.load(f)
                yield obj
                return
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                f.seek(start_pos)
                json_str = f.read(e.pos)
                obj = json.loads(json_str, encoding = 'utf-8')
                start_pos += e.pos
                yield obj

The first object is parsed correctly; the next ones are not.
While testing random values of f.seek(start_pos), I see there is an inconsistency with the index found by except json.JSONDecodeError as e:. Why is this index different than the number of characters shown when I select on the IDE the text up until the character where the JSON object ends on the file?
How can I ensure the objects will be parsed correctly?
I tried to get f.seek(start_pos) for the second JSON object at debug prompt, but it differs greatly from e.pos thrown by the error.
A sample JSON is here:
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "profile": {
      "name": "Alice",
      "age": 30
    }
  },
  "product": {
    "sku": "A1234",
    "details": {
      "name": "Laptop",
      "price": 999.99
    }
  }
},
{
  "user": {
    "id": 2,
    "profile": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 22
    }
  },
  "product": {
    "sku": "A123w",
    "details": {
      "name": "Laptop",
      "price": 9.99
    }
  }
}


Post an example of the data, otherwise no one can help you

Please update your question with some small examples of the contents of the file. It is unusual to try to use json to load from a file when you are expecting decode errors.

I am trying to use the error approach to detect the end/beginning of each object. A link to a JSON sample was provided. If there is a more elegant solution for this, with no extra imports, I am glad to learn

json.load(f) is going to read the entire file contents.  I don't understand why you're using the word "streaming" here.  a json file must, by definition, contain ONE outermost object.

To be more clear, I have edited; it is a webscraped string containing two json objects. I would like handle each one separately. json.load(f) returns JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 955 column 6 (char 33213) with the file provided.

Questions should include everything necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself, not in a 55 kB externally hosted file that expires in 6 days. Try to find a minimal reproducer - it shouldn't take 55 kB.

"tried to get f.seek(start_pos) for the second JSON object at debug prompt" - what happened then?

Also, seeking to arbitrary positions in text mode is undefined behavior.

"it is a web-scraped string".  How was the scraping done?  The fix could be to generate the data differently instead of writing an invalid JSON file.

This is definitely not the way, how it should be done, but I'll suggest a workaround for your certain situation.

json.load(f) returns JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line

The problem is that your "json" is not really a json, because there are missing brackets [] for list of objects and a lot of duplicated keys. But as a workaround you can do the following:
import json

with open("test.json", "r") as file:
    str_data: str = file.read()
    data: list[dict] = json.loads(f"[{str_data}]")

for item in data:
    ...


amazing solution! exactly the solution I was hoping for. მადლობა!

Yes, this can be done, but I'm not recommending this.
Your problems are:

You have added encoding='utf-8' to json.loads()
You are ignoring the comma that is separating your json objects

I've tested this code:
def stream_read_json(fn):
    start_pos = 0
    with open(fn, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                obj = json.load(f)
                yield obj
                return
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                f.seek(start_pos)
                json_str = f.read(e.pos)
                obj = json.loads(json_str)
                yield obj
                f.read(1)
                start_pos += e.pos + 1

I've also tested this code which only uses values recovered from f.tell() as the parameter to f.seek() as recommended in the documentation.
def stream_read_json(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                start_pos = f.tell()
                obj = json.load(f)
                yield obj
                return
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                f.seek(start_pos)
                json_str = f.read(e.pos)
                obj = json.loads(json_str)
                yield obj
                f.read(1)


so it seems there was a mismatch on the index because of the different encodings used to read the data. well noticed!
